# Route not firing Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-core

I'm not sure what is wrong with my route. the breakpoint is not firing when I try to access the route.

here is the source message from googles advanced rest client

```
POST /api/menu HTTP/1.1
HOST: localhost:6223
content-type: application/json
content-length: 34

{ "app_id": 99999, "user_type": 2}
```

Here is my controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MenuController : Controller
{
    private MenuRepo xMenuRepo;
    public MenuController(IOptions<SqlConnectionStringsList> iopt)
    {
        xMenuRepo = new MenuRepo(iopt);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<Menu> GetMenuItems([FromBody] MenuQuery menuq)
    {
        List<Menu> xMenuList = new List<Menu>();
        xMenuList = xMenuRepo.GetMenuItems(menuq.app_id, menuq.user_type);
        return xMenuList;
    }
}

public class MenuQuery
{
    public int app_id { get; set; }
    public int user_type { get; set; }
}
```

I placed a breakpoint on `GetMenuItems` and it is not even firing. The response is a 500 internal server error. This project only has two routes, the default ValuesController with a new project, and this MenuController. I can't find any additional place to specify routes in the project, other than at the top of the controller. But the ValuesController works! I can't figure out what is wrong!?

Answer (score 2):

Route for action is missing

[Routing to Controller Actions: Attribute Routing](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/routing.html#attribute-routing)

> [Mixed
>   Routing](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/routing.html#mixed-routing)
>
> MVC applications can mix the use of conventional routing and attribute
>   routing. It’s typical to use conventional routes for controllers
>   serving HTML pages for browsers, and attribute routing for controllers
>   serving REST APIs.
>
> Actions are either conventionally routed or attribute routed. Placing
>   a route on the controller or the action makes it attribute routed.
>   Actions that define attribute routes cannot be reached through the
>   conventional routes and vice-versa. Any route attribute on the
>   controller makes all actions in the controller attribute routed.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MenuController : Controller
{
    private MenuRepo xMenuRepo;
    public MenuController(IOptions<SqlConnectionStringsList> iopt)
    {
        xMenuRepo = new MenuRepo(iopt);
    }

    //POST api/menu
    [HttpPost("")]
    public IEnumerable<Menu> GetMenuItems([FromBody] MenuQuery menuq)
    {
        List<Menu> xMenuList = new List<Menu>();
        xMenuList = xMenuRepo.GetMenuItems(menuq.app_id, menuq.user_type);
        return xMenuList;
    }
}
```

Comment: In human terms this means? if I place a Route `api/[controller]` on the controller, I will need to specify the route for each action. Action meaning `GetMenuItems` with the attribute meaning `[HttpPost]` is missing a route `("")`?

Comment: Yes. HttpPost without a route works for conventional routing. You could just as easily used `[HttpPost][Route("")]` but [HttpPost] allows for the route to be included in the attribute. Checkout the documentation linked to in the answer to get a better understanding of routing in asp.net core

Comment: I got tripped up, because I thought it was implied I guess.

Comment: I had to remove the answer check, this did not work. Same results 500 internal server error and breakpoint on method not hit.

Comment: Then try debugging the pipeline for the request. The issue then could probably not be route related but related to an error in your code. start working backwards from the controller to narrow down what is causing the error. put a break point in the constructor and make sure that the controller is being created correctly. from there check startup configuration. It would help if you can get the error message associated with the 500

Comment: I did find it, it was related to the setting I was injecting. I can't get "List" based settings to work. Creating a stand alone connection string worked! I took out the route you provided in your answer to test and see if it worked without the `("")` It worked, because it is implied.